# Accessing multiple json arrays from one file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have multiple arrays stored in a PHP file like this:

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'bear', 'tiger');
$house = array('couch', 'tv', 'chair', 'table', 'lamp');
```

I'm accesing this from the PHP like this:

```
$animals[0] ---> returns cat
$house[1] ---> returns tv
```

However I need to convert all this into JSON and store it in an external file.
I tried doing this:

```
{"animals":["cat", "dog", "bear", "tiger"]},
{"house":["couch", "tv", "chair", "table", "lamp"]}
```

And then my PHP is something like this

```
$json = file_get_contents('data/default.json');

$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

However when i try to echo soemething from this array it either gives me an error or just a blank screen.

I tried multiple ways:

```
$array["animals"][0]
$array[0][0]
```

I don't know if my problem the json formatting or the way I'm accesing it or maybe I'm not converting it to an array. Can someone please explain how this should be done?

Comment: can you `var_dump($array)` ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: yes first of all check `print_r($array);` or `var_dump($array);`

Comment: Why don't you json_encode, before storing to the file?

Comment: var_dump($array) returns null and print_r($array) returns 1

Comment: Try to use json_encode

Comment: Put you initial arrays into one, then json_encode them and after that put them into the file.

Comment: To convert the php array to json?

Comment: if it returns null your json data is malformed

Comment: `var_dump($json );` to know what you are getting from the file.

Comment: ok i converted it with  `json_encode` and it gives this 
    `[["dog","cat","tiger","bear"],["couch","table","chair","tv"]]`
but now i don't have the names of the arrays, how can i add names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these arrays:

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'bear', 'tiger');
$house   = array('couch', 'tv', 'chair', 'table', 'lamp');
```

With this code:

```
$json = json_encode( array( 'animals'=>$animals,'house'=>$house ) );
echo $json;
```

you will obtain this JSON:

```
{"animals":["cat","dog","bear","tiger"],"house":["couch","tv","chair","table","lamp"]}
```

With this code:

```
$json = json_encode( array( array('animals'=>$animals),array('house'=>$house) ) );
echo $json;
```

you will obtain this JSON:

```
[{"animals":["cat","dog","bear","tiger"]},{"house":["couch","tv","chair","table","lamp"]}]
```

When you start from an array, using built-in function `json_encode` is the better way to **obtain a valid JSON**.

Comment: I think this is what I need. After that how to acces them one by one with `json_decode`

Comment: Try it with `json_decode` and see the structure. BTW, in the first example, you can access it by `$decodedJson->animals`, in second example by `$decodedJson[0]->animals`. If your main keys are uniques (animals, house, etc... ) I suggest you first example.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Looks like my JSON was invalid at first. That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The comma after the `animals` lists, `..."tiger"]}, <--`, indicates that these two lists are part of a larger structure that we're not seeing in the JSON you posted.

Try changing your JSON to:

```
{
    "animals": ["cat", "dog", "bear", "tiger"],
    "house": ["couch", "tv", "chair", "table", "lamp"]
}
```

Test:

```
$json = '{"animals": ["cat", "dog", "bear", "tiger"],"house": ["couch", "tv", "chair", "table", "lamp"]}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo $array1["animals"][0]."\n";
echo $array1["animals"][1]."\n";
echo $array1["house"][1]."\n";

/* 
Output:

cat
dog
tv
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you should try this way

```
{
    "animals": ["cat", "dog", "bear", "tiger"],
    "house": ["couch", "tv", "chair", "table", "lamp"]
}
```